# Gradle 3.1 gives the error: "Build failed with exception, Could not initialize class" for any command

Tags: gradle

I just installed Gradle on my Centos 7 CM, both using `sdkman` and `wget` as suggested on the [Offical Gradle website](http://www.gradle.org/downloads?_ga=1.177111085.902698333.1474446238)

I also set `GRADLE_HOME` to the correct directory.

However when I run `gradle -v --debug` I get this:

```
10:01:03.295 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Initialized native services in: /root/.gradle/native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not initialize class org.fusesource.jansi.internal.CLibrary

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Whats going wrong?

**UPDATE**
Installing `gradle-2.14.1` and `gradle-3.0` seems to work fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution listed is one way to make it work, but I suspect the original person might have their /tmp directory mounted noexec, and if that is the case, then there is a less drastic solution.

The temporary workaround (if using the wrapper script) is to alter gradlew to include this or something similar so that the jansi .so file gets extracted to some temporary location that is *NOT* mounted noexec:

DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-Dlibrary.jansi.path=${HOME}/.gradle"

BTW, you cannot shove this value into a gradle.properties system property because this class gets loaded before those properties are loaded.

jansi 1.13 seems to include an older version of hawtjni from 2014, but even the latest version appears to do this same thing:
https://github.com/fusesource/hawtjni/blob/3d3aa0be17cc8d35e251ea3594b1e684ce919d0d/hawtjni-runtime/src/main/java/org/fusesource/hawtjni/runtime/Library.java#L153

You could adjust -Djava.io.tmpdir because of this section of code:
https://github.com/fusesource/hawtjni/blob/3d3aa0be17cc8d35e251ea3594b1e684ce919d0d/hawtjni-runtime/src/main/java/org/fusesource/hawtjni/runtime/Library.java#L227

It would be nice if the ClassDefNotFound error would show the UnsatisfiedLinkError and likely complaint about not being able to load the shared library from /tmp, but it does not, even as part of the cause.

Gradle internally setting this system property to something like the gradleUserHome directory seems like it should be trivial, but interestingly enough where this occurs in the code is in the logging subproject which doesn't have any easy way to depend upon the 2 other subprojects that already have convenience classes to look up gradleUserHome.

Comment: My issue was I had `noexec` on the temp folder

Answer (score 0):

Check your system to make sure you have free space available on your disk -
I had this exact error, then realised my disk was full.

After freeing up some space Gradle 3.1 started to work again without error.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle 3.2 resolves this issue, which was due to this bug in jansi: https://github.com/fusesource/jansi/issues/55